# Parsing t=1h2m3s(h - hour, m-minutes, s-seconds ) into seconds if order of hours, minutes and seconds are valid

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to parse only valid timestamp formats as below

1. hours followed by minutes followed by seconds  ex:t=1h2m3s
2. minutes followed by seconds ex:t=2m3s
3. only hours   ex: t =3h
4. only minutes ex: t =4m
5. only seconds ex: t =5s

and escape other timestamp formats like t=2m1h or t=3s2m or t=3s1h2m.

I tried as below but unable to escape invalid formats.I am trying with the regular expression to find.

```
 function calculateInSeconds(timeStamp) {
        var timeInSeconds=0;
        console.log("calculateInSeconds timeStamp:"+timeStamp);

        timeStamp.replace(/([0-9]+)[h|m|s]/g, function(match, value) {
            if (match.indexOf("h") > -1) {
                timeInSeconds += value * 60 * 60;
            } else if (match.indexOf("m") > -1) {
                timeInSeconds += value * 60;
            } else if (match.indexOf("s") > -1) {
                timeInSeconds += value * 1;
            }

        });
        console.log("timeInSeconds"+timeInSeconds);

    }
calculateInSeconds("t=20m2s");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first check that the order matches then, if it does calculate the time in seconds.

```js
function calculateInSeconds(timeStamp) {
  var timeInSeconds=0;
  console.log("calculateInSeconds timeStamp:"+timeStamp);
  if(timeStamp.match(/t=[0-9]*h?[0-9]*m?[0-9]*s?/g).toString()==timeStamp){
    timeStamp.replace(/([0-9]+)[h|m|s]/g, function(match, value) {
       if (match.indexOf("h") > -1) {
          timeInSeconds += value * 60 * 60;
       } else if (match.indexOf("m") > -1) {
                timeInSeconds += value * 60;
       } else if (match.indexOf("s") > -1) {
                timeInSeconds += value * 1;
       }
     });
   }
   console.log("timeInSeconds"+timeInSeconds);
}
calculateInSeconds("t=1h2m");//3720 valid
calculateInSeconds("t=2m1h");//0 invalid
```

Answer (score 0):

Use optional quantifier.

```
t=(?:(?:\d{1,2}h)?\d{1,2}m)?\d{1,2}s
```

or

```
t=(?:(?:(?:1[012]|[1-9])h)?(?:[1-5]?\d|60)m)?(?:[1-5]?\d|60)s
```

Comment: `t=(?=\d+[hms])(?:\d{1,2}h)?(?:\d{1,2}m)?(?:\d{1,2}s)?  `

Comment: Above expression is selecting seconds and minutes from invalid formats like t=20s10h, t=20m10h which needs to be escaped

Comment: you need to add `\b` , ``t=(?=\d+[hms])(?:\d{1,2}h)?(?:\d{1,2}m)?(?:\d{1,2}s)?\b  ``

Answer (score 0):

Check the following regular expression:

```
([0-0]?[0-4])[h]([0-5]?[0-9]|60)[m]([0-5]?[0-9]|60)[s]
```

Comment: but then, 5 hours isn't valid :p